# Visio 2013 won't allow master shape edit even with protection turned off

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I've made a new stencil, I've dropped in a shape to edit, I'm editing it.  It's a swimlane, and I want to rotate the title block.  I've turned on developer mode, and put protection to "none".

I can see the rotation handle but I can't drag it.  I can select rotate 90 degrees right, but it just doesn't happen.

I've had a look at the layers, but there doesn't seem to be a check box next to "lock" as I've seen described.

I just want to change the shape and it's not letting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Protection section in the ShapeSheet is one way that properties can be locked, but another is directly using the GUARD(...) function in a cell. Check the Angle cell to see if the formula is guarded.

Comment: This tells me why - Thanks! But is it possible to remove the Guard?  I've googled but don't seem to be finding an answer.

Comment: Did you finally figure out how to remove the protection/GUARD from the formula? I have unselected all checkboxes in the Protection dialogue box (Developer Tab->Shape Design group->Protection). I have all values set to 0 in the Protection section of the ShapeSheet. Despite all that,the height and angle formulas are "GUARD(0.2 in)"  and "GUARD(0 deg)" respectively & wont change. Yet I can visually (w/ mouse) resize & change the shape angle and height w/o problem, & yet those formulas wont change and they evaluate to 0.2 inch and 0 deg respectively regardless of how the shape actually looks like!

Comment: You need to use the ShapeSheet directly to delete the GUARD( from the start of the formula, and ) from the end of it.

Comment: You can open the ShapeSheet of a selected shape using the Developer tab. You can open the Developer tab by ticking Developer Mode in the Advanced tab of File / Options